# Why does the set of solutions to a non-homogeneous system of linear equations include the basis for the kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

For this problem, I am specifically referring to a system of linear equations with $m$ linear equations and $n$ unknowns. I understand how everything is solved, but I am intrigued why the basis for the null space is in the answer. If $m<n$ and the system is consistent then there are infinitely many solutions. For example consider the system:
$$3x_1+2x_2+3x_3-2x_4=1$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=3$$
$$x_1+2x_2+x_3-x_4=2$$
Then by solving and setting $x_3=t$ as a free variable, the solution for the system is $s=(1,2,0,3)+t(-1,0,1,0):t\in\mathbb{R}$. But we see that the vector $(-1,0,1,0)$ is a basis for the homogenous equation. Why is it that the basis for the homogenous system of equation appears in the solution for the non-homogenous case?

Comment: If $x_0$ and $x_1$ are solutions of $Ax=b$ then $x_1-x_0$ is a solution of $Ax=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first rewrite your set of equations using matrices as $ AX = Y$ where
$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 2 & 3 & -2 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad Y = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  3 \\
  2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 and \, X = \begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
  x_3 \\
  x_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we manage to find a vector $X_0$ such that $AX_0 = Y$ then adding any vector $X_1$ from the kernel to the initial solution $X_0$ leads to $A(X_0 + X_1) = AX_0 + AX_1 = Y + 0 = Y$ which means that $X_0 + X_1$ is also a solution to $AX = Y$.

I hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!